# Пунктуация: "Я милая(,) и у меня красивые ноги"

Tags: пунктуация

Нужны ли знаки препинания?

Я милая и у меня красивые ноги.

Answer (score 7):

"Я милая, и у меня красивые ноги." Нужна запятая между двумя частями сложносочинённого предложения.